# Filter by date on view is very slow

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have an inkling what's causing the slowdown. The issue is that I'm not sure what the correct solution.

I have the following underlying query in my view (named `vMemberListByDate`):

```
select
      mpi.membermpi
    , mpi.accountnumber
    , mpi.MemberKey
    , membergroupkey = m.groupkey
    , mpi.accountkey
    , cr.CreditScore
    , m.HashedSSN
    , OpenDate = mpi.AccountOpenDate
    , Closedate = mpi.AccountCloseDate
    , Tenure = DATEDIFF(MONTH, mpi.AccountOpenDate, mpi.SnapshotDate)
    , AgeIndex = db.Sort
    , mpi.SnapshotDate
    , ShareBalanceAmt = fmad.TotalShareBalance
    , cr.TotalUnsecuredBalance
    , CreditLineBalance = fmad.CreditLineLoanBalance
    , MortgageBalance = fmad.FirstMortgageLoanBalance + fmad.SecondMortgageLoanBalance
    , cr.RevolvingBalance
    , IsActive
    , fmad.LastChargeOffDate
    , fmad.TotalChargeOffCnt
into 
    #Results
from
    EDW.Global.vFactMemberMPIDaily as mpi (nolock)
inner join 
    EDW.Global.DimMember as m (nolock) on m.MemberKey = mpi.MemberKey
inner join 
    EDW.Global.FactMemberAccountDaily as fmad (nolock) on fmad.AccountKey = mpi.AccountKey 
                                                       and fmad.SnapshotDate = mpi.SnapshotDate
left join 
    EDW.Global.DimBand as db (nolock) on isnull(datediff(year, BirthDate, mpi.SnapshotDate), -1) between db.LowValue and db.HighValue 
                                      and db.GroupDescription = 'Age 2'
left join 
    EDW.Global.DimCredit cr (nolock) on cr.HashedSSN = mpi.HashedSSN 
                                     and mpi.SnapshotDate between cr.StartDate and cr.EndDate
```

I select from the view as follows:

```
select count(*)
from ML.vMemberListByDate
where SnapshotDate = '11/1/2022'
```

It runs excruciatingly slow at 26 minutes total.

However, if I apply this date filter directly in the view's query code, it runs in 10 seconds. My assumption for the slowdown is that the view returns every row possible before filtering, therefore causing the slowdown.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Well - have you looked at the **actual** execution plan of a select against that view? That would probably tell you where most of the time is wasted ...

Comment: It seems the issue was resolved with option(recompile). Hadn't used that before but did some research and that's what I found!